# Generate unique combinations from multiple arrays/vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, unique, combinations

I have 800 data files and each file contain 8 lines of integer eg

```
17,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,16,20,22,24,26,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
16,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,16,17,21,26,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
23,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,23,25,26,28,29,35,36,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
27,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,17,19,20,21,22,23,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,34,37,39,40,41,42,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
27,14,16,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,35,36,37,38,39,40,42,43,44,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
24,20,24,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
16,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
14,35,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Each line has 50 elements, 1st element of each line is number count i.e. 17 of line 1 indicate there is 17 numbers in this line 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12,13,15,16,20,22,24,26. Numbers in each line is unique , in ascending order and within range 1~49.
My task is to generate list of unique 8 numbers combinations from this 8 lines 
i.e. A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
A from line 1, B from line 2 ... H from line 8

24,517,914,624 (17*16*23*27*27*24*16*14) entries will be generated:

```
1,1,4,8,14,20,33,35
...
1,1,4,8,14,20,33,49
....
1,2,4,8,14,20,33,35
...
2,1,4,8,14,20,33,35
...
```

And then process the 24,517,914,624 entries list as follow:

i) remove entries with duplicate numbers e.g. 1,1,4,8,14,20,33,35 and 1,1,4,8,14,20,33,49 will be removed

ii) sort number in each entry in ascending order e.g. 2,1,4,8,14,20,33,35 will become 1,2,4,8,14,20,33,35

iii) remove duplicated entries e.g. 2,1,4,8,14,20,33,35 is same as 1,2,4,8,14,20,33,35 after sorted, therefore only 1 entry of 1,2,4,8,14,20,33,35 will be kept
After the above process, may be around 10 millions entries left (which is the result I want)

However. processing a 24,517,914,624 entries array is a nearly impossible task,
therefore I tried the following 2 approachs to tackle the problem (try remove entries with duplicate numbers and sort number for each entry.

1) Brute force approach, use 8 nested for loop to generate combinations:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LineArr[0][0]; i++) {
 for (int j = 0; j < LineArr[1][0]; j++) {
  for (int k = 0; k < LineArr[2][0]; k++) {
   for (int l = 0; l < LineArr[3][0]; l++) {
    for (int m = 0; m < LineArr[4][0]; m++) {
     for (int n = 0; n < LineArr[5][0]; n++) {
      for (int o = 0; o < LineArr[6][0]; o++) {
       for (int p = 0; p < LineArr[7][0]; p++) {
        MyRes[0]=LineArr[0][i]
        MyRes[1]=LineArr[1][j]
        MyRes[2]=LineArr[2][k]
        MyRes[3]=LineArr[3][l]
        MyRes[4]=LineArr[4][m]
        MyRes[5]=LineArr[5][n]
        MyRes[6]=LineArr[6][o]
        MyRes[7]=LineArr[7][p]
        // Sort number of MyRes and discard if it contains duplicate numbers
        // store valid combination in a temp array/vector
        }}}}}}}}
        // remove duplicate entries in the temp array/vector ('unique' the temp array)
```

2) Stepwise approach
Instead of generate 8 numbers combination at once, generate 2 numbers combination from first 2 lines, sort number in each entry, remove entry with duplicate number and unify the list
the output will be something like this:

```
1,2
1,3
1,4
```

1,1 2,2 will be removed and 4,1 will become 1,4 and duplicated entries removed.

Then the above list will combine with line 3 to form 3 numbers combinations, also sort and remove entries with duplicated number and unify the list.
Apply the above to 4,5,6...8 lines to form 4,5,6...8 numbers combinations

Since this is part of an automation project, AutoIt is used throughout the project (those 800 files 
are from another 3rd party software). I tried implement the combinations generation with AutoIt, 
Technically approach 1) generate 24,517,914,624 entries, sort number in each entry right after generation and discard entry with duplicate number in it.
This approach takes forever to run since it involve billions entries to test/sort and its array size is much higher than AutoIt's array size limit (16 millions). Therefore approach 1) can be discarded,
it only suitable for (at most) 5 numbers combination (eg 1,3,7,14,23).

For approach 2), I tried 2 variations:

i) store the result in each step in temp array and use AutoIt's _ArrayUnique function to remove duplicate entries. This also takes forever to run!!

ii) Instead of store the result in temp array, I make use of SQLite, i.e. put the combination generated in each step into a single row table in SQLite, the table/row is created with PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE Then I select the row back into AutoIt for further processing.

Variation ii) eventually work, it takes 1 hr 20 min to handle 1 file (and I have 800 of such files)

Now I plan to implement the combination generation in VC++ (VS 2017) and I have the follow questions:

1) Apart from "Brute force" and "Stepwise", any other approach/algorithm to generate unique combinations from multiple arrays/vectors from performance point of view ?

2) To sort number in each entry and check repeat number in each entry, I think std::sort, std::search/std::find will do the job,  however, since there will be millions entries to check, is there any other options from performance point of view ?

3) To remove duplicate entries (unify the combination list i.e. get unique combinations), I should use std::unique or still rely on SQLite ? since the size of array may as large as 30~40 millions and shrink to 10 millions after std::sort and std::unique or SELECT from SQLite (don't know which implementation is better in performance point of view)

4) Any ready made LIB can easy the task ?

Thanks a lot.

Regds

LAM Chi-fung

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just find out the std::set, and its sort/unique feature suit my need. I implement the stepwise approach with it and the program run like fly. Only that it easily go out of memory after row 6, so I combine it with SQLite i.e. after work on 6 rows, I discard the std::set and store the combined result in SQLite table (single row table with PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE). This may not be a perfect solution but workable.